# Correctly deallocating MTAudioProcessingTapRef in swift3.2/4

Tags: objective-c, swift, audio, avplayer, avplayeritem

I have been working with an MTAudioProcessingTapRef in my project in order to analyze the buffer data in real-time while playing streaming audio. The thing is I can't get the tap processor to deallocate correctly when I need it.

I have an AudioViewController swift class with a reference to my AudioTapProcessor objective-C class, the swift class is in charge of telling the processor to start and stop the processing for the AVPlayerItem. The processor has also a delegate(the view controller in this case) to inform about buffer changes while processing.

My problem is if I declare the processor delegate as weak(as it should be), the processor will randomly crash trying to inform an already deallocated delegate because the process method of the tap processor got executed a few times after the stop processing call.
The only way I found to fix this is to declare the tap processor delegate as a strong property, which obviously causes a retain cycle and my AudioViewControllers will never get deallocated.

Below, some code that could help you relevant from de situation:

AudioTapProcessor.h

```
@interface AudioTapProcessor : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) AVPlayerItem *item;
@property (nonatomic, strong) id<AudioProcessorDelegate> delegate;

- (instancetype)initWithDelegate:(id<AudioProcessorDelegate>)delegate 
    item:(AVPlayerItem *)item;
- (void)startProcessing;
- (void)stopProcessing;

@end
```

AudioTapProcessor.m

```
void init(MTAudioProcessingTapRef tap, void *clientInfo, void 
**tapStorageOut) {
    *tapStorageOut = clientInfo;
}

void finalize(MTAudioProcessingTapRef tap) {}

void prepare(
         MTAudioProcessingTapRef tap,
         CMItemCount maxFrames,
         const AudioStreamBasicDescription *processingFormat
         ) {}

void unprepare(MTAudioProcessingTapRef tap) {}

void process(
         MTAudioProcessingTapRef tap,
         CMItemCount numberFrames,
         MTAudioProcessingTapFlags flags,
         AudioBufferList *bufferListInOut,
         CMItemCount *numberFramesOut,
         MTAudioProcessingTapFlags *flagsOut
         ) {
 //Random crashes here if I declare the delegate weak
 //Something like AUDeferredRenderer-0x7ff8f448ef (364): EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)
  AudioTapProcessor *processor = (__bridge AudioTapProcessor *)MTAudioProcessingTapGetStorage(tap);

  OSStatus err = MTAudioProcessingTapGetSourceAudio(tap, numberFrames, bufferListInOut, flagsOut, NULL, numberFramesOut);

  AudioBuffer *pBuffer = &bufferListInOut->mBuffers[0];
  UInt32 frameLength = pBuffer->mDataByteSize / sizeof(float);
  float *pData = (float *)pBuffer->mData;

  if (err == noErr && processor) {
    if ([processor.delegate 
      respondsToSelector:@selector(updateWith:withSize:)]) {
      [processor.delegate updateWith:pData withSize:frameLength];
    }
  }
 }

- (void)stopProcessing
{
  [self.item removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status"];
AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *params =
(AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *) _item.audioMix.inputParameters[0];
  MTAudioProcessingTapRef tap = params.audioTapProcessor;
  self.item.audioMix = nil;
  CFRelease(tap);
  //By doing this the tap processor does call its unprepare and finalize methods, so it is being deallocated fine.
}
```

Then in my AudioViewController.swift I have:

```
var processor: AudioTapProcessor!

override func prepareForPlayback() {
  super.prepareForPlayback()
  if processor == nil {
    processor = AudioTapProcessor(delegate: self, item: item)
    processor.startProcessing()
  }
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
   super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
   player.pause()
}

deinit {
  //I tried to do this early in the lifecycle(viewWillDissapear) and it is the same thing.
   processor.stopProcessing()
}
```

Any hint would be appreciate, im going crazy with this. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Works for all iOS versions**

⇨ **Understanding the root cause**

1.AudioTapProcessor.m Initialization

*callbacks.clientInfo* holds a pointer to **self**.
This is not a weak or strong reference just a C pointer. So if self get dealloc'ed we context->self points to a **bad memory address**

```
- (AVAudioMix *)audioMix {
    if (!_audioMix) {
        AVMutableAudioMix *audioMix = [AVMutableAudioMix audioMix];
        if (audioMix) {
            AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *audioMixInputParameters = [AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters audioMixInputParametersWithTrack:self.audioAssetTrack];
            if (audioMixInputParameters) {
                MTAudioProcessingTapCallbacks callbacks;

                ...
                callbacks.clientInfo = (__bridge void *)self;
                ...
            }
        }
     }
}
```

2.AudioTapProcessor.m processCallback

Everytime processCallback is called there is a safety check to see if self is being dealloc'ed but remember in step 1. above that even if self is dealloc'ed **context->self is not nil but points to a bad memory address** resulting in a **EXC_BAD_ACCESS**.

```c
static void tap_ProcessCallback(MTAudioProcessingTapRef tap, CMItemCount numberFrames, MTAudioProcessingTapFlags flags, AudioBufferList *bufferListInOut, CMItemCount *numberFramesOut, MTAudioProcessingTapFlags *flagsOut) {
    ...
    MYAudioTapProcessor *self = ((__bridge MYAudioTapProcessor *)context->self);
    if (!self) {
      NSLog(@"AudioTapProcessor - processCallback CANCELLED (self is nil)");
      return;
    }
    NSLog(@"AudioTapProcessor - processCallback PROCESSING");
}
```

⇨  **Now, how to Solve this?**

1.ViewController.swift or owner of audioTapProcessor

```swift
deinit {
  print("ViewController - Dealloc")
  audioTapProcessor.stopProcessing()
}
```

2.AudioTapProcessor.m

We need a way to tell our audioTapProcessor to stop the processCallback.
The simplest and natural way is to use the check already in place in processCallback above if **(!self) return;**

So stopping the audioTapProcessor is just correctly setting **context->self to NULL**.

```c
- (void)stopProcessing {
    NSLog(@"AudioTapProcessor - stopProcessing");
    AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *params = (AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *)_audioMix.inputParameters[0];
    MTAudioProcessingTapRef audioProcessingTap = params.audioTapProcessor;
    AVAudioTapProcessorContext *context = (AVAudioTapProcessorContext *)MTAudioProcessingTapGetStorage(audioProcessingTap);

    // nils out the pointer so that we know in tapProcessorCallbacks that self will be dealloc'ed
    context->self = NULL;
}
```

⇨  **As a result the lifecycle is corrected**

Instead of this

1. ViewController - Dealloc
2. AudioTapProcessor - stopProcessing
3. AudioTapProcessor - processCallback PROCESSING
4. EXC_BAD_ADDRESS

We get this

1. ViewController - Dealloc
2. AudioTapProcessor - stopProcessing
3. AudioTapProcessor - processCallback CANCELLED (self is nil)
4. AudioTapProcessor - unprepareCallback
5. AudioTapProcessor - finalizeCallback
6. AudioTapProcessor - Dealloc

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving the issue by making the `MTAudioProcessingTapRef` to retain its `AudioTapProcessor` parent. That way they are not deallocated at different moments of the lifecycle.

Changes to the original code:

1.First, we make the delegate a weak variable as it should be:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<AudioProcessorDelegate> delegate;
```

2.Then, we pass a retained reference of self(Our AudioTapProcessor) to the created `MTAudioProcessingTapRef`:

```
 callbacks.clientInfo = CFRetain((__bridge void *)(self));
```

3.Also created a custom context to pass data along the tap:

```
typedef struct TapProcessorContext {
  void *self;
} TapProcessorContext;

void init(MTAudioProcessingTapRef tap, void *clientInfo, void **tapStorageOut) {
  TapProcessorContext *context = calloc(1, sizeof(TapProcessorContext));
  //Initialize TapProcessorContext context.
  context->self = clientInfo;

  *tapStorageOut = context;
}

void finalize(MTAudioProcessingTapRef tap) {
  TapProcessorContext *context = (TapProcessorContext 
*)MTAudioProcessingTapGetStorage(tap);
  // Clearing the context. THIS IS KEY TO DEALLOCATE THE AUDIOTAPPROCESSOR
  CFRelease(context->self);
  context->self = NULL;

  free(context);
}
```

4.Finally, I applied a workaround to a know bug in iOS to our stopProcessing method:

```
- (void)stopProcessing
{
   if ( @available(iOS 11.0, *) ) {
    // Starting with iOS 11, it is not required to manually nil audioTapProcessor,
    // but we need to retain the audioMix for a bit to make sure the processing callback
    // will not be called after we release (this is due to a bug in iOS 11 which calls the release
    // callback but still calls the processing callback afterwards - it also releases internal data
    // on release, so simply checking for release in the processing block is not enough)
    // rdar://34977000
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      [self releaseTap];
    });
  } else {
    // Prior to iOS 11 we need to manually nil the audioTapProcessor
    [self releaseTap];
  }
}

-(void)releaseTap {
  AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *params = (AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *) _item.audioMix.inputParameters[0];
  params.audioTapProcessor = nil;
  _item.audioMix = nil;
}
```

Comment: I added a boolean `invalid` flag to the `TapProcessorContext` struct, and set the flag before the call to `dispatch_after`.  If the flag is set when `tap_ProcessCallback` is called, I also return immediately.